# Connection error with Docker Swarm in Gitlab Runner - half bare - half containers

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, docker-swarm, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to use Docker Swarm with a Gitlab Runner to roll out deployments on 5-6 servers.

The swarm atm consists of 1 manager (call it M1), 2 workers (W1 and W2). My Gitlab Runner is using a docker executor with a docker in docker image. When a commit occurs, the Runner tries to register as a manager in the swarm (so it can start jobs / services). However I get the following error:

> Error response from daemon: manager stopped: can't initialize raft node: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = could not connect to prospective new cluster member using its advertised address: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: **IPADDRESS** connect: connection refused"

Interestingly, the ipaddress in the error is not the ip address of any of the servers. They are in sequence, and the one in the error message is the direct next address.

Is there a better way to issue commands to my swarm from my runner / a computer not connected to the server?